# parsing json for decode not working

Tags: php, json

I am getting json string from database when i am trying to parse to decode it's showing nothing

```
$apiContent = "[{"caseid":2,"fullname":"df","businessname":"asdf","phonenumber":"12345678","activity":"sdf","province":7,"wilayat":"adfasd","description":"sfasdf","casedate":{"date":"2018-02-08 11:39:19.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Muscat"}}]"

print_r(json_decode($apiContent, TRUE));
```

Comment: It is not showing because you are not printing it.

Comment: try `$apiContent = json_decode($apiContent, TRUE); var_dump( $apiContent );`

Comment: i tried it too when i echo $apicontent it's showing but when i try to use json_decode it's showing nothing

Comment: And also try to wrap the json string with `''` and not `""`

Comment: Right now, it not a valid string, since you have unescape `"` inside it.

Comment: how i resolve it ??

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the json string with `''` and not `""`

Using `"` will not make your string valid.

```
//            -------- Use ' instead of " (Also use this on the end of the string )
//            v
$apiContent = '[{"caseid":2,"fullname":"df","businessname":"asdf","phonenumber":"12345678","activity":"sdf","province":7,"wilayat":"adfasd","description":"sfasdf","casedate":{"date":"2018-02-08 11:39:19.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Muscat"}}]';
$apiContent = json_decode($apiContent, TRUE); 
var_dump( $apiContent );
```

This will result to:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'caseid' => int 2
      'fullname' => string 'df' (length=2)
      'businessname' => string 'asdf' (length=4)
      'phonenumber' => string '12345678' (length=8)
      'activity' => string 'sdf' (length=3)
      'province' => int 7
      'wilayat' => string 'adfasd' (length=6)
      'description' => string 'sfasdf' (length=6)
      'casedate' => 
        array (size=3)
          'date' => string '2018-02-08 11:39:19.000000' (length=26)
          'timezone_type' => int 3
          'timezone' => string 'Asia/Muscat' (length=11)
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you mess with quotes.

```
<?php 

  $apiContent = '[{"caseid":2,"fullname":"df","businessname":"asdf","phonenumber":"12345678","activity":"sdf","province":7,"wilayat":"adfasd","description":"sfasdf","casedate":{"date":"2018-02-08 11:39:19.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Muscat"}}]';

  $t = json_decode($apiContent, TRUE);

  var_dump($t);
```