# how to read json from database

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have json string in database

```
{"api":[{"caseid":2,"fullname":"df","businessname":"asdf","phonenumber":"12345678","activity":"sdf","province":7,"wilayat":"adfasd","description":"sfasdf","casedate":"2018-02-08 11:39:19"},{"caseid":3,"fullname":"\u0646\u0648\u0631\u062e\u0627\u0646 \u062a\u0627\u062a\u0627\u0631\u064a","businessname":"\u0627\u0644\u0631\u0641\u062f","phonenumber":"98818663","activity":"\u0646\u0649\u0633 \u064a\u0634\u064a \u0647\u062e\u0634 \u0645\u062a \u0634\u064a\u0628\u0634\u0633","province":1,"wilayat":"\u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u0628","description":"\u0648\u0635\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0643\u0648\u064a","casedate":"2018-02-08 12:14:24"},{"caseid":4,"fullname":"test","businessname":"asdf","phonenumber":"12345678","activity":"asdfas","province":3,"wilayat":"dfasdf","description":"fsdfasdfasdf","casedate":"2018-02-08 12:24:53"},{"caseid":5,"fullname":"\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0627\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645","businessname":"\u0635\u0646\u062f\u0648\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0641\u062f","phonenumber":"98818663","activity":"\u0649\u0646 \u0633\u0634 \u0646\u062e \u0645\u0643 \u0648\u0646\u062e \u0635\u062e\u0636 \u062d\u062e\u0634","province":1,"wilayat":"\u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u0628","description":"\u0634\u0628 \u0634\u0633\u064a\u0628 \u0634\u0633\u064a\u0628 \u0634\u0633\u0628 \u062b\u0636\u0635  \u0631\u062b\u0631\u062b \u0631\u062b\u0631\u0631 \u0629\u0645 \u0629\u0648\u0648 \u0646\u0646\u062e\u062d","casedate":"2018-02-12 11:23:38"},{"caseid":6,"fullname":"\u0641\u0647\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0627\u0631\u062b\u064a","businessname":"\u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 ","phonenumber":"95871817","activity":"\u0644\u0627 \u064a\u0648\u062c\u062f ","province":1,"wilayat":"\u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u0628 ","description":"\u062a\u062c\u0631\u0628\u0629 1 ","casedate":"2018-02-13 13:40:51"}]}
```

$apiContent have above json string

```
$apiContent = $this->db->from("users_api")->get()->row()->apicontent;
```

when i write echo $apiContent it's shows the whole string but when i try to decode json string it's shows nothing

```
print_r(json_decode($apiContent, TRUE));
```

here is my whole function

```
function saveImportComplaint($xp)
{       
        $apiContent = $this->db->from("users_api")->get()->row()->apicontent;               
        return json_decode($apiContent, TRUE);      
}
```

After adding makejsonsafe function i can read and convert json, error coming because of unicode value

```
function makejsonsafe($myjsonstring)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) 
    {
        $myjsonstring = str_replace(chr($i), "", $myjsonstring);
    }
    $myjsonstring = str_replace(chr(127), "", $myjsonstring);
    if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($myjsonstring), 'efbbbf')) 
    {
        $myjsonstring = substr($myjsonstring, 3);
    }
    $myjsonstring = json_decode( $myjsonstring );
    return $myjsonstring;
}
```

Comment: [AGAIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771113/parsing-json-for-decode-not-working/48771216#48771216) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing json for decode not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771113/parsing-json-for-decode-not-working)

Comment: @Butuzov now i added my json string in database

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain now it's a different scenario

Comment: It is Unclear why your code isn't working.  Show us: `$apiContent`. There is something that you aren't telling us.

Comment: @mickmackusa i already write in my question $apiContent have above json string comes from the database

Comment: I just copied your json string to https://jsonlint.com/ and it does, in fact, validate.  So you are doing something wrong and we can't help you without knowing more.  You say that the json string is what is in the database ... but is that what is _actually_ being delivered to `$apiContent`?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes dud i also checked my string in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ it's showing perfectly but i don't know why it's not decoding in my function

Comment: I am not familiar with ci, so can you try `echo gettype( $apiContent );` and check what is the result?

Comment: I'd like to see: `if((@json_decode($apiContent,true))===null && json_last_error()!==JSON_ERROR_NONE){
       echo json_last_error();
    }`

Comment: @mickmackusa yes it's return 4

Comment: My first suspicion is the unicode values.  Are you following "UTF-8 All The Way Through"? (Have you read that one?)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through  This might explain why other resources are validating properly, yet your application chokes.  Also, what php version are you on?  It might not matter, just thought I'd ask.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes you are right and i found the solution by adding this function function makejsonsafe($myjsonstring)
 {
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) 
  {
   $myjsonstring = str_replace(chr($i), "", $myjsonstring);
  }
  $myjsonstring = str_replace(chr(127), "", $myjsonstring);
  if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($myjsonstring), 'efbbbf')) 
  {
   $myjsonstring = substr($myjsonstring, 3);
  }
  $myjsonstring = json_decode( $myjsonstring );
  return $myjsonstring;
 }

Comment: Please do your best to post an educational answer which will serve to help future readers.  Posting the solution as a comment is really hard to read.  Then you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @EvilInc. Do not add the solution to your question as an Edit.  Please post an answer to your own question -- this is totally legitimate and helpful.  Also include some explanation as to why your method works and what each step is going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are dealing with:

1. a Byte Order Mark
2. and potentially some unicode / zero-width characters

Without seeing your actual input string, I can't confidently write a perfect pattern or test my code, but my method should accomplish what your posted workaround does...

```
function makejsonsafe($myjsonstring){
    return json_decode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]|^\xEF\xBB\xBF/u','',$myjsonstring));
    // return the data as an object
}
```

Pattern Breakdown:

```
[                #start character class
    \x00-\x1F    #match range between "null" and "unit separator"
    \x7F         #match "delete"
]                #end character class
|                #or
^\xEF\xBB\xBF    #match your BOM at start of string
```

---

All that said, a shorter pattern may do the same trick:

`\p{Cc}` is the same as `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]`, so you might use: `/\p{Cc}|^\xEF\xBB\xBF/u`

`\P{C}` will only target printable characters, so you might use the inverse: `/\p{C}+/u`

References:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php